# Doxygen and Compile Time switches

Tags: c++, doxygen

In our software we have some compile time switches (defines) which compile for different targets. Each target has different features. But some are common for different targets.

What is the best way to generate Doxygen documentation that include documentation for all features.

For now I set the defines for the target with the most available features in my Doxygen configuration file. But then the documentation for some features are missing completly in the generated documentation.
I don't want to build the whole documentation for every target since a lot of the features are common for all of them.

Any best pratices for that?

Thaks

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... Why don't you just define all these switches in doxygen configuration file ? (with PREDEFINED). Did you check [this page](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/preprocessing.html) ?